# I have a problem when building database using Xcode

Tags: xcode9

[image]

Hello can someone please take a look at this code, I am having problems trying to adjust this code but I am also very new to Xcode 9 and will need help with the part

Comment: Could you paste your entire code of this part here, for us analyze? It seems you have forgot some declaration

Comment: hi, thank you for the reply but fortunately I managed to solve the problem

Comment: could you please post your solution for others learn from you?